# High poly lag limitation of blender?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I have a lag problem with my high poly model 12000000 poly, I made a quick video to illustrate my problem 
https://youtu.be/luvN2IeYqNg
When the mouse is out of the 3d view it lags a lot. I have to unselect the model, select an other or refresh the page to have no more lags
I have a quatro m5000
A gtx 1080
2x xeon e5 v4 2,4 ghz
256go ram
Ssd drive 
All drivers are ok 
I should be smooth ! 
The problem is coming from my computer ? Blender ? 
I need to work on high poly models for my work in archaeology

Comment: 12000000 faces :O. It's a **really huge amount**! Why don't you retopologize the model and bake normals?

Comment: Blender doesnt handle such a huge amount of polygons very well.

Comment: Yes it is ! I'm used to work with models with even more poly  I will try this, but I'm afraid to loose details :/

Comment: That's what I m thinking maybe the problem is coming from blender (I was thinking it was the falt of nvidia drivers)

Comment: @XavierVillat I try to do most of the work of 3d scans outside of blender, and then bake displacement and normals on retopologized model in blender.

Answer (score -2):

I remeshed, with meshlab and reduced the model to 3millions poly ant no more lags I definitely thinks it's a blender issue :(